# How to use Docker compose in c program?

Tags: c, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to isolate my development environment to create a project in C. But I don't know how to use Docker with C. I'm getting confused about running the program and I would like someone to help me. Take for example a "hello world" with an input. basic as a program. How can I make a docker compose and how to run it. And still with live-reload?

hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int numero;

  // Pede um número ao usuário
  printf("Digite um número: ");
  scanf("%d", &numero);

  // Exibe o número digitado na tela
  printf("O número digitado foi: %d\n", numero);

  return 0;
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcc:latest

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/

RUN gcc -o app hello.c

CMD [“./app"]
```

Comment: As a rule, compiled languages like C don't support live reloading (Docker or otherwise); you need to recompile and relink the program whenever you make a change.  The use of `scanf()` to read from stdin will make this program hard to run in a Compose environment.

Comment: The question makes little sense to me. You built a simple container image from a C program - how would compose get into the mix? If you have a Dockerfile that builds a service, you can create a compose.yaml that references it as the build context. You can then use `docker compose watch` to rebuild and restart the service automatically whenever the build context is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice (although not required) to treat containers as **immutable**.

In this scenario, whenever your code changes, you rebuild and create a uniquely new image.

There are various ways to work with **mutable** containers:

1. Use a container interactively e.g. Bash to edit the code, compile it etc.
2. Mount host files into a container (possibly in combination with #1)
3. Copy files in|out of a running container

Some combination of these approaches may serve your needs but be careful to ensure you do so correctly so that you persist changes to files in the container:

You can create an interactive shell on a container from the `gcc:latest` image and mount files e.g. your source code into a folder on it:

```bash
WORK="/app"

docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--volume=${PWD}/hello.c:${WORK}/hello.c \
--workdir=${WORK} \
gcc:latest
```

This will mount `${PWD}/hello.c` into the container's `/app` folder and make this the working directory.

When you run the `docker` command, you should see:

```
# ls
hello.c
```

You can then:

```
# gcc -o hello hello.c
# ls 
hello hello.c
# ./hello
Digite um número: 55
O número digitado foi: 55
```

Any changes you make to `hello.c` (only) will be reflected in the copy on your host.

Comment: Seems work for me. Let me see if i understand. These comands you dive me are in terminal when i execute the docker image, right? So i created a interactive shell that i can use and execute my program, if I make any change in my program files these changes will be reflected in my container, right? Are some whay to improve these big command, some file that can contain this command and transform it into a single?

Comment: Yes, the commands prefixed `#` are in the container's shell. Because `hello.c` is mounted into the container from the host (`--volume=...`), changes to the `hello.c` file in the container are changes to the `hello.c` file on the host. You can mount arbitrary folders|files this way.

Comment: There are many other ways to interact with containers but it would not be possible to fully explain these here. I encourage you to read the documentation which is comprehensive and to read blogs etc.

Answer (score 1):

`CMD ["./app"]`

Try this as a CMD command in `Dockerfile`. I found `“` in your CMD makes docker build fail.

In addition, you don't want to copy source codes and build docker images every time you make changes on your project.

You can also consider using `bind mount` or `docker volume` to share directories across native host and containers.

Comment: Since C is a compiled language, you need to recompile the program every time you make a change anyways, and rebuilding a Docker image is not that expensive.  I would _not_ use any sort of mount here.